# how to get tuesdays to mondays every week starting from tuesday

Tags: date, range

I am trying to sum a coloumn in my database and it must start from tuesdays to mondays every week. i.e, the current week of my calculation should be from 4th Oct to 10th Oct and it is meant to reset every tuesdays.

I made this code

```
<?php
$refdate = strtotime(date('o-\WW'));
$tuesday = strtotime("+1 day",$refdate);
echo date("M j, Y", $tuesday) . "<br>";
?>
```

to

```
<?php
$refdate = strtotime(date('o-\WW'));
$monday = strtotime("next monday",$refdate);
echo date("M j, Y", $monday) . "<br>";
?>
```

But today, instead of getting 4th to 10th Oct, I am getting 11th to 17th Oct. Please someone help me. I am confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

date function return the current week, which starts from monday (10th), and you are adding one to the date, which makes it 11th.
Next monday is simply 17th.

```html
<?php
//default get last tuesday
$startdate = "last tuesday";
if (date('N') === '2')
{ 
  // its Tuesday today
  $startdate = "today";
}
$start_week = strtotime($startdate);
$end_week = strtotime("next monday",$start_week);
$start = date("M j, Y",$start_week); 
$end = date("M j, Y",$end_week);
echo $start ."<br>";
echo $end."<br>";
?>
```